# How to allow inline-javascript in Safari and Epiphany?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm having a huge project with many onclicks and inline-scripts. But now people who use the epiphany browser or safari complained that all of the javascript does not work. I tested this and it's true. There are thousands of messages like

```
Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

In epiphany. I tried setting the CSP-header to all kinds of things I found online, including

```
    $headerCSP = "Content-Security-Policy:".                                                                                                                        
            "connect-src 'self';". // XMLHttpRequest (AJAX request), WebSocket or EventSource.                                                                      
            "default-src 'self';". // Default policy for loading html elements                                                                                      
            "media-src 'self';". // vaid sources for media (audio and video html tags src)                                                                                                  
            "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';".                                                                                                                                           
            "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';";                                                                                                                                            
    header($headerCSP);                                                                                                                                                                     

    header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';");                                                                                                                 
    header("X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");                                                                                                                            
    header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';");
```

But none of them made a. the message go away from the developers console or b. repair the issue.

Creating nonces is not an option since I don't have the time, energy and money to fix thousands of calls. What am I doing wrong?

I even tried setting the CSP in the html-headers

```
<meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

But nothing works. Still the same message.

What can I do about this?

I understand the risks of allowing inline-code, but there's sadly no way around this. The page works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, modern versions of IE and even Chrome, on which I read that CSP is usually very strict. There are no errors there.

Comment: This is one of the headers I opted to *not* support due to the documentation not be *sufficient* (it's not horrible, just not sufficient). Beyond that *and* the complications of how I'd implement it in to my own platform I am *not* going to manage to be first to get it figured out though I want to wish you the best of luck.